# How to export 'raw' data from fabric.io events / answers

Tags: google-fabric

I have setup some events like login and some other custom events in fabric.io / answers. Now I see those events appear in the dashboard. But I would like to see corrolation between events. For example, with the login event I also sent the username.
Now I would like to select a username and see how many times he/she logged in and if it failed or not and which login option he/she used.
The graphs in the dashboard are just for one item and not combined items.
So I would like to export the raw data so I can do this myself in excel for example.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric now allows you to [export raw event data into Firebase and Big Query](https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/android-export-firebase.html), which can then be used to construct your own reports.